# Should [react-google-maps] be re-tagged as [google-maps-react]

Tags: discussion

I just came across an edit where someone replaced [react-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-google-maps) [google-maps-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-react)

Are they one and the same thing?

If so should [react-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-google-maps) be re-tagged as [google-maps-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-react)

Neither of them have a Wiki.

[react-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-google-maps) has 7 questions

[google-maps-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-react) has 15 questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a closer look,both refer to two different packages in npm.

1. all questions in [react-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-google-maps) refer to the package [react-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps) which can be found [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps).
2. questions in [google-maps-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-react):

   - retagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487215/react-google-maps-how-to-use-fitbounds-panby-panto-pantobounds-public-apis),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888706/react-google-map-directionsrenderer-issue),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707612/react-google-maps-cant-get-bounds) to [react-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-google-maps) as it refers to library in point 1.
   - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262744/how-create-arc-line-and-animate-it-at-react-google-maps) also seems to refer to the wrong library but looks too broad.
   - All other questions refer to [google-maps-react](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react)
   - Question [Using with React-DnD with Google-Maps-React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636902/using-with-react-dnd-with-google-maps-react) seems to be referring to a third library entirely [google-map-react](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react). I am refraining from touching this as I am unable to currently find a tag for this.

I do not agree either tag need to be retagged to the other or burninated(as per the tag request in the question).

Comment: Agreed. But someone needs to edit those tag wikis!

Comment: Quite agree with Cody, both of them need to have tag wikis, especially explaining the difference between the two.